# fork system call: Does the parent's preallocated memory gets allocated again for the children?

Tags: c, memory-management, fork, copy-on-write

```
int *g=NULL;

main()
{

g = malloc(40000000);//allocate 40MB in the parent

fork();

while(1);

}
```

If I run this program and watch the same in the top, I see the 40MB memory allocated against the parent and also the child.

But in the background I expected the copy on write to prevent the double allocation of memory, because I have not touched it yet..

Comments? Is COW specific to some platforms? How can I test if COW is indeed the way for fork?

Answer (score 4):

Logically the child process has the 40MB of memory allocated to it, it just doesn't get a separate copy until it modifies it.

The COW operation doesn't change the amount of resources that are allocated to a process.  Instead it just prevents physically duplicating them until an edit is made at which point the new process needs a separate copy.

Comment: >it just doesn't get a separate copy until it modifies it.

Comment: it just doesn't get a separate copy until it modifies it.. Q1. Is there any way I can see this savings done (because I have not modified the memory) Q2. Is there any sample test program which illustrates that the memory is the same (shared) until written..

Comment: Check the /proc/$PID/smaps file of your processes - see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33381/getting-information-about-a-process-memory-usage-from-proc-pid-smaps